# Find and replace text problem in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

In photoshop, let's say I have a few texts layers with contents like this:

```
Text layer 1:  1@@text01@@abc
Text layer 2:  2@@text02@@cef
Text layer 3:  3@@text03@@hgi
```

I would like to replace all the layers texts (the content of each text layer inside the artboard, not the layer panel's names) starting with the `first@` and the `end@`, that is `@@text..@@` to `##` so that results will be:

```
Text layer 1:  1##abc
Text layer 2:  2##cef
Text layer 3:  3##hgi
```

Hoe can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do basically 3 operations:

- traverse through the layers and select them one by one;
- replace a part of the layer name using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern;
- rename the layer with the new name;

A basic* version of this could look like this:

```js
var layer;

// looping through top layers
for (var i = 0; i < activeDocument.layers.length; i++) {
  layer = activeDocument.layers[i]; // for ease of read
  activeDocument.activeLayer = layer; // making the layer active
  layer.name = layer.name.replace(/@.*@/,'##'); // replacing the layer name. @.*@ regex pattern will select anything between two @ symbols
}
```

*Update*: replacing the layer text contents.

Basically the same thing with some additions. You need to check if `layer.kind` is `LayerKind.TEXT` and instead of changing `layer.name` you need to change `layer.textItem.contents`

*. note that `activeDocument.layers` collection contains only top level layers. If your document has groups (aka folders) or artboards you'll need to go through nested layers with a different function: something like [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/photoshop-script-iterating-through-all-layers-and-groups-to-export-tagged-layers-in-javascript/m-p/10853278#M297061)

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. Actually, I do want to replace the content of the text layers inside the artboard instead of the text layers of the panel.

Comment: One last thing and everything is done. If I want to replace whatever words before the @, for example, eeeeee@abc, all the "eeeee", how to writhe the pattern? Should I writh like this:  layer.name = layer.name.replace(/.*@/,'eeeee')

Comment: remove the first `@` in regex

Comment: It works great! Thank you.I will try to learn photoshop script for the passion like you :)

Comment: Great to hear that! Please don't forget to accept the answer to resolve the question

Comment: I would like to accept the answer, but I just can't find the button for me to do that, or I missed something.

Comment: it's an v-like icon on the left of the answer

Comment: Thanks. The script works fine. But one thing I encountered is that the replacement function runs from the top layer to the bottom. However, in some case my top layers are not text layers, the script will then prompt the message “not text layers” and the scripted stopped. I will like to know if the script can only focus on all text layers and skip other type of layers and still run successfully.

Comment: In my answer I've mentioned that you need to change the layer kind.

Comment: That’s perfect. I have done this and works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself with the script below, it does works, but don't know if there is any structure I missed:

```html
var layer;

// looping through top layers
for (var i = 0; i < activeDocument.layers.length; i++) {
  layer = activeDocument.layers[i]; // for ease of read
  activeDocument.activeLayer = layer; // making the layer active
  layer.name = layer.name.replace(/@.*@/,''); // replacing the layer name. @.*@ regex pattern will select anything between two @ symbols
  layer.textItem.contents = layer.textItem.contents.replace(/@.*@/,''); // replacing the layer name. @.*@ regex pattern will select anything between two @ symbols
}
```